# Getting undefined instead of Input Field value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [InputVal, setInputVal] = useState();
  const [ShowDiv, setShowDiv] = useState(
    <div>
      <p>Hello world. This is default "Show Div" value</p>
    </div>
  );

  const ChangeDivFunc = () => {
    setShowDiv(
      <div>
        <p style={{ color: "red" }}>
          Hello World. This is updated "Show Div" value
        </p>
        <input onChange={getInputval} type="text" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <button onClick={AlertVal}>Show Input Value</button>
      </div>
    );
  };

  const getInputval = (val) => {
    setInputVal(val.target.value);
  };

  const AlertVal = () => {
    alert(InputVal);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Example</h1>
      <br />
      <button onClick={ChangeDivFunc}>Change Div</button>
      {ShowDiv}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Code Flow:

1. Click **Change Div** button then it will show **Input field** and **Show Input Value** button.
2. Now, Enter some value in **input field** and click the **Show Input Value** button to get the value of input field.

Problem:
It returns **undefined** instead of **input field** value.

I'm trying to get the value of **Input field** when **Show Input Value** button is clicked. But I'm not getting the desired results.

Here's the Sandbox link : [Click for Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-resonance-nopj9?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not store html node inside state. You can simply store only a boolean value to switch between what node to show. I'm not pretty sure but it may cause weird behavior since React internally depends heavily on the DOM/HTML UI Tree (see [Managing State](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state)).

Try this instead:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState("");  // initialize as empty string.
  const [showDiv, setShowDiv] = useState(false);

  const changeDivFunc = () => {
    setShowDiv(true);
  };

  const getInputVal = (event) => {  // The arg is Event object, not val
    setInputVal(event.target.value);
  };

  const alertVal = () => {
    alert(inputVal);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Example</h1>
      <br />
      <button onClick={changeDivFunc}>Change Div</button>
      {
        showDiv? (
          <div>
            <p style={{ color: "red" }}>
               Hello World. This is updated "Show Div" value
            </p>
            <input value={inputVal} onChange={getInputVal} type="text" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <button onClick={alertVal}>Show Input Value</button>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <p>Hello world. This is default "Show Div" value</p>
          </div>
        )
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[Forked Codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-dan-kdyfx)